# Robot framework, Sikuli hello_world demo script is failing?

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

I have installed Robot framework 2.8.7 in a solaris server and added sikuli library to it . when tried to run demo script "Hello world" i'm getting the following error.

```
bash-3.2# pybot /robot/robotframework-SikuliLibrary-master/demo/hello_world/testsuite_sikuli_demo.txt

*[ WARN ] Test get_keyword_names failed! Connecting remote server at http://127.0.0.1:42821/ failed: <Fault 0: 'Failed to invoke method get_keyword_names in class org.robotframework.remoteserver.servlet.ServerMethods: java.lang.RuntimeException'>
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/robot/robotframework-SikuliLibrary-master/demo/hello_world/testsuite_sikuli_demo.txt': Initializing test library 'SikuliLibrary' with no arguments failed: Failed to get_keyword_names!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SikuliLibrary/sikuli.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.remote = self._connect_remote_library()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SikuliLibrary/sikuli.py", line 138, in _connect_remote_library
    self._test_get_keyword_names(remote)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SikuliLibrary/sikuli.py", line 155, in _test_get_keyword_names
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to get_keyword_names!')*
```

I have done the same setup on windows machine and it is working fine. Python version used in solaris is 2.6.Can you let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/295568

Comment: Please check the contents of these two file: {output folder}/Sikuli_java_stdout/stderr|stdout_{timestamp}.txt. Putting the file contents into your question may help us understand the problem. Also what is the version of Java you are using?